# cannot import name 'convert_examples_to_features' deeppavlov

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deeppavlov

I tried to run the snippet of code from the tutorial about NER from deeppavlov.

[Link tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/19-entities-for-104-languages-a-new-era-of-ner-with-the-deeppavlov-multilingual-bert-1bfa6d413ea6)

First I run command:

```
python -m deeppavlov install ner_ontonotes_bert_mult
python -m deeppavlov interact ner_ontonotes_bert_mult [-d]
```

Then

```
from deeppavlov import configs, build_model 
ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult, download=True)
ner_model(['World Curling Championship will be held in Antananarivo'])
```

Catch this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_examples_to_features'
```

So if paste code in VSCode, line

```
configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult
```

will give a signal that "Instance of 'Struct' has no 'ner' member"

(Config is Struct)

How I can fix it? 
Google didn 't find an answer

Comment: Welcome to SO Sambr The Slayer! Please edit your question and include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without it it may be hard to get the answer you are searching for. You shouldn't expect other people to follow the tutorial.

Comment: but I wrote the example, step-by-step. The link to the tutorial is just a code source.

Comment: Well, when I'm trying to reproduce it with a fresh environment, using your example code then `python -m deeppavlov interact ner_ontonotes_bert_mult [-d]` fails as long as `-d` is in brackets. Running the code below, doesn't give me the `ImportError`. From my perspective it's just not reproducible.

Comment: @SambrTheSlayer Please make sure you are using the latest version of DeepPavlov. In addition there are maybe some issue with requirements, please make sure that `install` went well.